# Acesso negado ao tentar efetuar push para Github

Tags: git

Estou tendo dificuldade para executar push para um repositório no GitHub:

```
remote: Permission to fabiojaniolima/laravel-boot.git denied to user123.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/fabiojaniolima/laravel-boot.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Não sei onde esta definido o usuário user123, meu objetivo é subir com o usuário fabiojaniolima, já procurei a configuração mas não encontrei, olhei nas configurações do projeto e global.

Comment: Já tentou `git config --global user.email`?

Comment: já olhei, esta definida como fabiojaniolima

Comment: retorna fabio-janio. Inspecionei com Sourcetree e não encontrei nenhum apontamento para essa conta user123 (obs: lembro de ter feito teste com essa conta alguns dias atrás)

Comment: Isso não é exatamente um e-mail, certo?

Comment: as variáveis user.email e user.name globais e locais do projeto estão com email e nome correto.

Answer (score 1):

Achei o problema, foi justamente o que eu menos esperava. Nas configurações do git estava tudo correto, o problema estava no chaveiro do MacOS, ele guardou um login antigo com o user123, quando eu executava um push ele estava considerando as credenciais do user123 e não a do usuário configurado no **~/.gitconfig** ou **.git/gitconfig**

Answer (score 0):

Verifique no arquivo "./.git/config" do repositório, ele pode estar configurado localmente com este usuário.